# angularjs disable does not work

Tags: angularjs

Why doesnt the ng-disabled work in my code?
I have created a plunker.. any suggestions?

https://plnkr.co/edit/j2LnhLxBe5gHPITMqzUJ?p=preview

```
<ul ng-repeat="permission in permissions" ng-click="permission.assigned=!permission.assigned">
  <a class="list-group-item" ng-class="{active: permission.assigned, disable: permission.name=='default'}">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type=checkbox aria-label="checkbox" ng-model="permission.assigned" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">{{ permission.name }}</div>
      <div class="col-md-6">{{ permission.description }}</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</ul>
```

Comment: where were you used `ng-disabled` directive..? please explain more

Comment: I don't see `ng-disable` in your HTML.

Comment: BTW, it's `disabled` class in bootstrap (Rather than `disable` as you use in your code), and as the above say - You don't use `ngDisabled` in your code

Comment: sorry i have edited it. in my ng-class i have disable option which does not seem to work. there is no ng-disable. my mistake

Comment: ah yes i changed that. but still im able to uncheck the check box. probably something to do with the stoppropagation ive used. just dont know how to work around it..

Comment: @Y.Hewa Add `ng-disabled="permission.name=='default'"` to `input type=checkbox`

Comment: even with that change im able to click outside the checkbox and it will uncheck ..

Comment: @Y.Hewa Yup. You need to do something with `ng-click="permission.assigned=!permission.assigned"` ==> `ng-click="permission.assigned = permission.name=='default' ? permission.assigned : !permission.assigned"` (For example)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your input element - `ng-disabled="permission.name === 'default'"`.

Comment: even with that change im able to click outside the checkbox and it will uncheck..

Comment: In that case also remove this - `ng-click="permission.assigned=!permission.assigned"` from your ul.

Comment: but i want to be able to check and uncheck without only clicking the checkbox.. is there any workaround without removing the ng click?

Comment: You can wrap the input in a label. If you style that label to cover the entire area you want to be clickable, it will work. Or change the `ngClick` on your ul to call a function and handle the disabled state there instead.